# Date modified of most recent file(s) in a set of sub-directories

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I need some assistance in creating an output file (or a 'report') based on a bunch of sub-folders. I want to email this report to myself nightly (I can handle the emailing of the file, just not sure how to create the actual file).

**My data structure:**

- Main working directory containing:

  - My .bat file which copies the data from 3 servers to the TFX Logs folder below
  - TFX Logs folder

    - Client folder(s)

      - Up to 15 days of .log files

**What I want to do:**

1. Copy data from 3 servers to TFX Log folder, maintaining the structure (TFX Log\Client\TFX_*.log) (**COMPLETED**)
2. Create a single .txt or .csv file with a list of the newest TFX_*.log files from each Client folder (just the newest - not all 15 files that are there). Something like this:

   Directory Name | File Name | Date Modified
3. Email file to myself (**COMPLETED**)

I just need help with number 2.

**This is what I have so far:**

```
:: Copying data

XCOPY "%source1%" "%destination%\TFX Logs\" /s /y
XCOPY "%source2%" "%destination%\TFX Logs\" /s /y 
XCOPY "%source3%" "%destination%\TFX Logs\" /s /y 

:: Deleting old output file before creating new one

DEL "%destination%\*.txt"

:: Creating new output file

powershell "& '%destination%\ListFiles.ps1'"

REN "%destination%\ImportReport.txt" ImportReport_%tday%.txt
```

**My Powershell script looks like this:**

```
Get-ChildItem "..Daily Report\TFX Logs\" -recurse -file | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} | Out-File "..Daily Report\ImportReport.txt"
```

**What I get right now is this:**

(I just want the latest file from each folder using the structure specified above in #2 if possible)

```
    Directory: ..\TFX Logs\Client1


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                              
----                -------------     ------ ----                              
-a---         4/22/2015   3:06 AM        329 TFX_db21_1522040304.log           


Directory: ..\TFX Logs\Client2


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                              
----                -------------     ------ ----                              
-a---         4/22/2015  12:22 AM        331 TFX_db4_1522040017.log            


Directory: ..\TFX Logs\Client3


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                              
----                -------------     ------ ----                              
-a---         4/21/2015   8:03 PM        329 TFX_db4_1521042002.log
```

**Cliff's Notes:**

I want to rearrange the output from PowerShell to be:

Directory Name (Directory) | File Name (Name) | Last Modified Date (LastWriteTime)

Without all that other stuff and all of that white space. Just a nice row by row output.

Also, if possible, if there is a blank folder in there (or there is a folder with files older than 15 days), to still show it in the report file, but with no records. This way I'll know that, hey, this client hasn't ran in a while and needs to be examined for sure.

**UPDATE 4/29/15**

Magoo's suggestion below showed promise but hasn't worked for me. It doesn't do anything. Anyone have any other ideas of how to improve upon what I already have?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "source1=U:\sourcedir"
SET "source2=U:\sourcedir2"
SET "source3=U:\source dir3"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"

DEL "%destdir%\*.txt"
FOR %%d IN ("%source1%" "%source2%" "%source3%" ) DO CALL :process %%d

GOTO :EOF

:process
ECHO(XCOPY %1 "%destdir%\TFX Logs\" /s /y
PUSHD %1
FOR /f %%a IN ('dir /b /o-d TFX_*.log') DO >>"%destdir%\ImportReport_%tday%.txt" (
 ECHO %~1,%%~ta,%%~za,%%a
 popd
 GOTO :eof
)
popd
GOTO :eof
```

This should solve your problem.

For testing, I used my `u:` drive and `destdir` as the destination diectoryname.

Simply delete the destination `.txt` files, then for the list of directory names, call a process which

- copies the logfiles The required XCOPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(XCOPY` to `XCOPY` to actually copy the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)
- switches to the target directory
- performs a directory-list i basic format of files matching the mask, sorted in reverse-date order
- outputs the directory name, filetime. filesize and name to the report file (I'll assume you've set `tday`)
- pops back the original directory and terminates the loop so that only 1 filename (the last chronologically) is reported.

Comment: Hi @Magoo, thank you for your response. However, your script doesn't seem to do anything. I replaced the necessary variables (destination, etc.). The window just flashes quickly. I tried changing the TFX Log folder to TFX Log2 to see if it would even create a new directory and it did not. This is with the ECHO removed.